# Join Two Data frame in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a use case in which I need to join two tables in lookup way. How I can achieve something like this is spark?

Table A:

| Key | type1 | type2 | type3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ALK1 | NAK1 | NAK2 | NAK3 |
| ALK2 | NAK4 | NAK5 | NAK6 |

Table B:

| Key | Data |
| --- | --- |
| ALK1 | G1 |
| ALK2 | G2 |
| NAK1 | G3 |
| NAK2 | G4 |
| NAK3 | G5 |
| NAK4 | G6 |
| NAK5 | G7 |
| NAK6 | G8 |

Result:

| Key | Data |
| --- | --- |
| ALK1 | G1,G3,G4,G5 |
| ALK2 | G2,G6,G7,G8 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join using `array_contains` then goupby and collect list of column `data`:

```scala
val result = dfA.as("a")
  .withColumn("keys", array(dfA.columns.map(col): _*))
  .join(
    dfB.as("b"),
    array_contains(col("keys"), col("b.Key"))
  ).groupBy("a.Key")
  .agg(
    concat_ws(",", collect_list(col("data"))).as("data")
  )

result.show
//+----+-----------+
//| Key|       data|
//+----+-----------+
//|ALK1|G1,G3,G4,G5|
//|ALK2|G2,G6,G7,G8|
//+----+-----------+
```